# android ViewPager height changed after RecyclerView data increased in Fragment in it

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I use a RecyclerView within fragment in a ViewPager, but something wrong after data of RecyclerView increased, the ViewPager moved up.

Finally,I solved it by using a ScrollView outside, and set set android:fillViewport="true" at ScrollView.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_group_purchase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="sizu.mingteng.com.yimeixuan.main.home.others.grouppurchase.activity.GroupPurchaseActivity">
    <!--工具栏-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_group_purchase" />

    <com.lcodecore.tkrefreshlayout.TwinklingRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout_home_group_purchase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tr_enable_loadmore="false"
        app:tr_head_height="120dp"
        app:tr_overscroll_bottom_show="false"
        app:tr_overscroll_top_show="false"
        app:tr_wave_height="120dp">


        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_group_purchase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--广告栏-->
                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                    <com.youth.banner.Banner
                        android:id="@+id/banner_home_group_purchase"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height" />
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                <!--类别Tab-->
                <include layout="@layout/layout_tab_more" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <!--分类视图-->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp_home_group_purchase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </com.lcodecore.tkrefreshlayout.TwinklingRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here I initialize my ViewPager

```
private void setTabLayoutAndViewPager() {
    mTabPagerAdapter = new GroupPurchaseHomeTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments, mTabs);
    vpHomeGroupPurchase.setAdapter(mTabPagerAdapter);
    mCurrentItem = vpHomeGroupPurchase.getCurrentItem();
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpHomeGroupPurchase);
}
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcE5d.gif

Comment: Can you share snippet of your code?

Comment: How can I share my code ? It`s my first time.

Comment: upload it on Github, bitbuket, dropbox, or google drive and provide me sharable link.

Comment: upload whole project or just the layout code?

Comment: oh,I found it and I  showed my layout code in my question

Comment: lao ge wen mei kan dong ni xiang gan sha ...

Comment: da xiong di wen ti jie jue le

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try call this method:

```
yourViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

More info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Sorry, I can't add comment.

UPDATE:

```
    private void setTabLayoutAndViewPager() {
        mTabPagerAdapter = new GroupPurchaseHomeTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments, mTabs);
        mTabPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        vpHomeGroupPurchase.setAdapter(mTabPagerAdapter);
        mCurrentItem = vpHomeGroupPurchase.getCurrentItem();
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpHomeGroupPurchase);
    }
```

Try this.
If it will now solve issue, show how you add data to your adapter.

Ooops. Apply this.

```
     private void setTabLayoutAndViewPager() {
                    mTabPagerAdapter = new GroupPurchaseHomeTabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments, mTabs);
                    if (vpHomeGroupPurchase.getAdapter() != null) {
                        vpHomeGroupPurchase.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    vpHomeGroupPurchase.setAdapter(mTabPagerAdapter);
                    mCurrentItem = vpHomeGroupPurchase.getCurrentItem();
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpHomeGroupPurchase);
                }
```

Comment: I called it after RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged but still not work.

Comment: Show java code, how You initialize ViewPager and increase it's adapter data please.

Comment: I showed my ViewPager init code, there are 4 Fragments in it and I just pull to load more data in RecyclerView within Fragment.

Comment: You may not understand my issue bro, I mean ViewPager`s height changed after a RecyclerView`s data increased in it, a gif in my question, check that please. Not the PagerAdapter issue.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry. Last that i can advise : try set android:fillViewport to true at ViewPager view.

Comment: Also, set android:layout_height="wrap_content", not match_parent

Comment: Finally,I solved it by using a ScrollView outside, and set set android:fillViewport="true" at ScrollView